# Why does the orderTotal variable get reset to 0.0 when exiting the getItems() function?

Tags: c++

I have this function that is supposed to keep a running total (orderTotal) until the user is done choosing items, yet when I debug I find that it keeps getting reset to 0.0 with each run through the menu:

Main function:

```
int main() {

    int choice = 0;

    welcome();

    do {
        displayMenu();
        choice = getChoice();
        getItems(choice, orderTotal);
    } while (choice != 4);

    output(orderTotal);
}
```

The variable orderTotal gets reset ever time the user goes through this function:

```
double getItems(int choice, double orderTotal) {
    char itemChoice = ' ';

    if (choice == 1) {
        cout << "Please choose an item (D, M or F):" << endl << endl;
        cout << "  D: Donut  - $" << DONUT_PRICE << endl;
        cout << "  M: Muffin - $" << MUFFIN_PRICE << endl;
        cout << "  P: Pastry - $" << PASTRY_PRICE << endl;
        cout << ">> ";
        cin >> itemChoice;
        itemChoice = tolower(itemChoice);

        switch (itemChoice) {
        case 'd':
            orderTotal += DONUT_PRICE;
            cout << "Total = " << orderTotal << endl;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            return orderTotal;
        case 'm':
            orderTotal += MUFFIN_PRICE;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            if (shopAgain == 'y') {
                return orderTotal;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

        case 'p':
            orderTotal += PASTRY_PRICE;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            if (shopAgain == 'y') {
                return orderTotal;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }

        default:
            cout << "Invalid choice, returning to main menu!" << endl;
            return orderTotal;
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 2) {
        cout << "Please choose an item (B or T): " << endl << endl;
        cout << "  B: Bagel  - $" << BAGEL_PRICE << endl;
        cout << "  T: Toast - $" << TOAST_PRICE << endl;
        cout << ">> ";
        cin >> itemChoice;
        itemChoice = tolower(itemChoice);

        switch (itemChoice) {
        case 'b':
            orderTotal += BAGEL_PRICE;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            if (shopAgain == 'y') {
                return orderTotal;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        case 't':
            orderTotal += TOAST_PRICE;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            if (shopAgain == 'y') {
                return orderTotal;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input, returning to main menu!" << endl;
            return orderTotal;
        }
    }
    else if (choice == 3) {
        cout << "Please choose an item (C or T): " << endl << endl;
        cout << "  C: Coffee  - $" << COFFEE_PRICE << endl;
        cout << "  T: Tea - $" << TEA_PRICE << endl;
        cout << ">> ";
        cin >> itemChoice;
        itemChoice = tolower(itemChoice);

        switch (itemChoice) {
        case 'c':
            orderTotal += COFFEE_PRICE;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            if (shopAgain == 'y') {
                return orderTotal;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        case 't':
            orderTotal += TEA_PRICE;
            cout << "Your total is: $" << orderTotal;
            shopAgain = anotherItem();
            if (shopAgain == 'y') {
                return orderTotal;
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        default:
            cout << "Invalid input, returning to main menu!" << endl;
            return orderTotal;
        }
    } 
    //return orderTotal;
}
```

I don't see where orderTotal is being reassigned...

Comment: You are passing by value - a copy. Pass by reference: `double getItems(int choice, double& orderTotal)`

Comment: However, I see you `return orderTotal;` In that case you can assign the result back to `orderTotal = getItems(choice, orderTotal);` Just make sure all paths return a value.

Comment: You are ignoring the return of the function at the place you call it.

Comment: That keeps the total, but then, when I pass that to the output function, it prints -nan(ind)... ?

Comment: Because you have `//return orderTotal;` at the end of the function so not all paths return a value. Uncomment that. Enable all compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missing something but it looks like you never declare and initialize the `orderTotal` variable in the main function. Also it looks like you aren't doing anything with the returned double from your `getItems` function. Perhaps try this:

```
int main() {

    int choice = 0;
    double orderTotal = 0.0;

    welcome();

    do {
        displayMenu();
        choice = getChoice();
        orderTotal = getItems(choice, orderTotal);
    } while (choice != 4);

    output(orderTotal);
}
```

Comment: I didn't include all of the code, and orderTotal is a global variable, declared above my prototypes.